# ¿Cómo concatenar INT y STR con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estoy intentando juntar texto y números.

Estoy haciendo algo mal y no sé qué sea:

```
l= "linea"
n= 2
w = "nueva"
f = w + l
print(f+" es test")
```

y la salida me da lo siguiente

```
nuevalinean es test
```

y está bien, sin embargo cuando agrego:

```
l= "linea"
n= 2
w = "nueva"
f = w + l
print(f)+repr(n)
```

entiendo que el comando **`repr( )`** sirve para convertir números en cadena, pero no consigo que mi salida sea correcta, la cual en teoría debería ser:

```
nuevalinea2
```

en vez de eso, recibo el siguiente error:

```
nuevalinea

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-2a5749fb6668> in <module>()
----> 1 print(f)+repr(n)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: La función apropiada para imprimir un objeto es str (). repr () regresa el código necesario para reconstruir el objeto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La función preconstruida [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) hace lo que piensas pero con algunos matices que puedes ver en la documentación, en teoría retorna una cadena que contiene la representación del objeto que se le pasa, el código Python que representa ese objeto en forma de cadena y con el cual podemos reconstruirlo, por ejemplo usando `eval()`.

El error se debe a que en realidad concatenas la salida de la función `print` (que no retorna nada) con el retorno de `repr` que es una cadena. Debería ser así:

```
print(f+repr(n))
```

Esta de todas formas, no es la manera de hacer lo que deseas aunque en este caso concreto funcione. Las formas correctas son las que te han proporcionado ya en las respuesta y otras dos que añado yo (todo para Python 3.x)

- Casting a str:

  ```
  l= "linea"
  n= 2
  w = "nueva"
  print(w+l+str(n))
  ```
- Método `format` de las cadenas:

  ```
  l= "linea"
  n= 2
  w = "nueva"
  print('{}{}{}'.format(w,l,n))
  ```
- `Print` separando cada variable por comas y usando el parámetro `sep`:

  ```
  l= "linea"
  n= 2
  w = "nueva"
  print(w, l, n, sep='')
  ```
- En Python >= 3.6 puedes usar los literales de cadena formateados:

  ```
  l= "linea"
  n= 2
  w = "nueva"
  print(f'{w}{l}{n}')
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Utiliza

```
l= "linea"
n= 2
w = "nueva"
f = w + l
print ("{} {}".format(f,str(n)))
// "nuevalinea2"
```

Comment: El usuario comenta que usa Python 3

Comment: Es verdad. quedaría así el print: `print ("{} {}".format(f,n))`

Answer (score 3):

solo pasando haciendo esto:
`str(variable)` y lo convierte a `string`(`str`)

```
l= "linea"
n= 2
w = "nueva"
f = w + l
print(f + str(n))
```

Output
`nuevalinea2`

Comment: una muy buena respuesta. muchas gracias

Comment: Recuerda ponerla como resuelta si es que te sirvio.

Answer (score 1):

Es más simple de lo que parece, simplemente hay que convertir la variable a str.

```
l= "linea"
n= 2
w = "nueva"
f = w + l
print(f+ str(n))
```

Pero ésta es una manera menos optimizada, realmente es mucho más simple si simplemente separas las variables por comas en lugar de usar el operador de concatenación.

```
l= "linea"
n= 2
w = "nueva"
f = w + l
print(f, n)
```

Comment: o usar *f-strings* `print(f"{f}{n}")`

Comment: Por cierto que diferencia hay con la otra respuesta?

Comment: FJSevilla ya ha hablado de esto. que hay de nuevo en tu respuesta? Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Amigo, la verdad no leí las otras respuestas, solo respondí con mi aporte, pero voy a tener en cuenta el leer otras respuestas antes de responder algo yo, así evito responder lo mismo que alguien ya haya respondido.

Comment: no te preocupes, poco a poco se va aprendiendo y de igual forma gracias por contribuir. Si estas de acuerdo con una respuesta votas a favor o puedes editarla si tienes algo que corregir o aportar :D